# Basic Laravel job throws: "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed" on failure

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, closures

I have created a very basic queue job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class FailingJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 1;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // nothing
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // nothing
    }

    /**
     * Called when the job fails
     *
     * @param Exception $exception
     */
    public function failed(Exception $exception) {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

and I dispatch it like so: **`FailingJob::dispatch();`**. This works fine.

Now I am purposefully adding **"bugged"** code in order for the job to fail, but instead of gracefully making the job fail,

**I get the following exception:**
`Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`.

I'm not sure where this is coming from, because this job is basically empty. I would like to use the `failed()` function in order to handle failures, but I can't even do that because this exception gets thrown when the job fails.

For reference, this is the code I use to make the job fail:

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    xxxxxx 
    // ^ This will make the job fail
}
```